# Why the results from running exactly the same regular expression twice are different?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the URL host part with a regular express in JavaScript. Suppose I have a URL

```
var str = 'www.demo-site.com:1234'
```

and I designed below regular expression to match it

```
var regex = /^www\.demo-site\.com(:\d+)$/gi
```

As I expected, `regex.test(str)` returns `true`. However, if I run it again, it returns false. Why the results from running exactly the same function twice are different?

`regex.test(str); //returns true`
`regex.test(str); //returns false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the search starts from the previous match for each invocation of `test`:

> test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test